# FuncAnimation save() gets stuck when running in background

Tags: python, matplotlib-animation

When trying to use the FuncAnimation save method using VSCode debugger - the code runs as expected. as well as when running it in the shell normally or using 'nohup' in the beginning.
However - when running it in the background from the shell using '&' - it is running up until the call to anim.save() and then gets to '[1]+  Stopped' status. If i move it to fg and then to bg again - it continues (until the next anim.save() call).
Any idea why it happens?

this is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def animate(frame_i):
    ax.collections = []
    ax.set_title(f'frame={frame_i}')
    ax.scatter(lmks_4d[frame_i,:,0], lmks_4d[frame_i,:,1], c='b')

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000, frames=lmks_4d.shape[0])
anim.save(out_path, fps=30)
```